# Xamarin new project error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I just started learning Xamarin and I am having some problems. I created a new  Android App Project, using a Single View App. I just open the activity_main.axml using the solution explorer and after it loads, i get the following error: "This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully, rendering might be affected." Even if I try to rebuild the solution, the error persists. 
Worth mentioning: this happens without editing/writing any code and without adding any objects through the toolbox.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to go on your project's folder and delete "bin" and "obj" folders from android project.
Clean your solution and then rebuild it, it may work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project on **Embedded Resource Environment**

then try to this step:-

-**Delete "obj" "bin"**

-**Clean Your project**

-**Re-build project**